# doctrine default values and relations

Tags: doctrine

In mysql I can set default value for column like this:

```
ALTER TABLE <Table> CHANGE <Column> DEFAULT <NEW_DEFAULT_VALUE>
```

I can retrieve default value:

```
SELECT DEFAULT(<Column>) FROM <Table> LIMIT 1
```

Is it possible to achieve this concept with Doctrine?

What I actually need is such methods in my table class:

```
class UserTable extend Doctrine_Table {
    /* ... */

    /** 
     * @return Doctrine_Record
     */
    public function getDefaultProperty() {
        return ???;
    }
    public function setDefaultProperty($value) {
        /* $value can be either integer or Doctrine_Record */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see if we can figure this out.

[Line 567 of `Record.php`](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Record.php.source.html#line561), part of the `assignDefaultValues()` method which populates defaults as the object is created, says:

```
$default = $this->_table->getDefaultValueOf($column);
```

So you don't actually need to add a `getDefaultProperty()`, you can use:

```
$userTable = Doctrine::getTable('User');
$defaultName = $userTable->getDefaultValueOf('name');
```

However, you seem to want `getDefaultProperty()` to return a `Doctrine_Record`. If you just want to get back a whole object that has all the default values set on it, I'm pretty sure you can just use:

`$defaultUser = new User();` (See the [Doctrine manual for Default Values](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models%3acolumns%3adefault-values/en))

But be sure that your defaults are defined in the schema.yml, not just in the database. Doctrine won't read defaults out of the database, and relies on the schema to tell it what to do.

Let me know how that works.

Cheers,
~J

Answer (score 0):

The Doctrine_Table class contains the getDefaultValueOf method which does what you're looking for. So, if you have a doctrine record, you can write something like: $record->getTable()->getDefaultValueOf('address_line_1'); where 'address_line_1' is a column. Hope this helps.